# In Fortran, how do I remove Nth element from an array?

Tags: arrays, matrix, fortran, intel-fortran

Eg I have array (/1,3,4,5,7,9,11/), how do I remove its 3rd element? I couldn't find an array function which does that, nor I find a loop an elegant solution, since I don't know how to append to an array (this means, add an element next to the previous defined element.)

I want to remove all even elements from an array... I know there is only one.

I can find its index using [**MINLOC**](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/MINLOC.html), but I don't know how to remove an element from array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let

```
a = (/1,3,4,5,7,9,11/)
```

then

```
pack(a,mod(a,2)/=0)
```

will return the odd elements of `a`.  This isn't quite the same as removing the 3rd element, but your question suggests that removing the even element(s) is really what you want to do.

If you declare

```
integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: oddones
```

then

```
oddones = pack(a,mod(a,2)/=0)
```

will leave `oddones` containing the odd elements of `a`.  You'll need an up-to-date compiler to use this automatic allocation.

Note that in Fortran, as in any sane language, arrays are of fixed size so removing an element isn't really supported.  However, if `a` itself were `allocatable` then you could use `a` on the *lhs* of the expression.  Let's leave it to the philosophers whether or not `a` remains the same under this operation.

Comment: I may add, that it is not necessary to `allocate` the array `oddones` in the newer versions of Fortran, because this is automatically done by the assignment (see F2008 7.2.1.3). This behaviour is also shown in the first quote of @Svetlana's answer.

Comment: Yes, indeed, as I wrote *You'll need an up-to-date compiler to use this automatic allocation.*

Comment: Thanks. I took the liberty to add links to documentation of PACK for various compilers to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used FORTRAN in a while, but look at the functions CSHIFT and EOSHIFT. I think you can't change the size of the array.

Comment: So your suggestion is to `cshift` the array until the value you want is at the end, then `eoshift` it out of the array (and introducing a `0` on the other end), and then `cshift` the array back to it's original form? Seems awfully convoluted.

Answer (score 1):

A working example, thanks to [this discussion](http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.fortran/how-to-insert-or-delete-element-to-a-list-i/595414). Thanks, Dick Hendrickson and Dave Frank.

Quote:

> *joel GUERRERO* wrote 
>   (Thursday, September 02, 2004 6:29 PM)
>
> > I have this question, how can I do to add a record or to delete a
> >     record from a list or array n fortran 90??
> >
> > That is, let suppose that I have the following array:
> >
> > (1 4 3 9 10 2 15 8)
> >
> > And I want to add the value 13 in the 4th position in order to obtain:
> >
> > (1 4 3 13 9 10 2 15 8)
>
> You asked above several weeks back, which led to my asking the newsgroup what syntax F2003 adds to facilitate this operation.
>
> Dick Hendrickson's response indicates below would work using F2003
>   syntax.
>
> ```
>  integer,allocatable :: v(:) 
>  v = [1, 4, 3, 9, 10, 2, 15, 8]
>  v = [v(:3), 13, v(4:)]   ! insert 13 into expanded size v at v(4)
> ```
>
> dave_frank 9/3/2004 8:07:59 AM

Working answer: as asked, removes 1 matching item only:

```
  program hello
     integer a(8)
     integer b(7)
     a=[1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13]
     index = minloc(a, dim=1, mask=(mod(a, 2) .eq. 0))
     b=[a(1:index-1), a(index+1:size(a))]
     print *, b
  end program Hello
```

You may be able to loop, "while (index)" with additional edits as necessary, to remove all matches, if you like.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with a fixed maximum size, but want dynamic behaviour within, you can just shift the elements:

```
integer, parameter :: max=10
integer :: a(max)
integer :: length_a, index, i
length_a = 8
a(1:length_a)=[1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13]
!remove (third) element
index = 3
do i=index,length_a-1
  a(i)=a(i+1)
end do
length_a=length_a-1
```

The advantage is that this does not use an array temporary.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do some slicing.

```
integer, parameter:: max = 10
integer used ! number of elements used
integer, dimension(1:max):: store
...
used = max
...
! Remove element n
if (n > 0 .and. n < used) then
    store(n:(used - 1)) = store((n+1):used)
end if
if (n > 0) used = used - 1
```