# How to best implement a Fortran equivalent to Matlab's intersect function

Tags: matlab, fortran

I'm surprised there's no intrinsic routine for this but I need a code snippet that should take two presorted 1D integer arrays and return elements present in both arrays in an efficient manner.

```
integer, allocatable :: A (:), B(:), C(:)
A=[1,2,3,6,10]
B=[3,10,5]

C=intersect(A,B) !< returns [3,10]
```

What's the best way to implement this in Fortran, or is a there a good open source implementation I can look at? I also could not find it in Numerical Recipes or Rosetta code.

Comment: [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: You can check how Octave does it https://github.com/NexMirror/Octave/blob/53bad7604f15491a7a22e1029bd21ec075000057/scripts/set/intersect.m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)), or sort both, or sort the shortest and do a binary search with the elements of the other.

See also Arjen Markus' [FLIB](http://flibs.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I would personally start with using sort. Doing sort on both allows for something of a metric of delta between the two sets...

Answer (score 2):

`pack(a, [(any(b == a(i)), i=1, size(a))])`

Comment: But I just wanted this was a thing: `pack(a, any(b == a))`

Comment: This is the crux move, which you can wrap with dynamic allocation of arrays (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21398212/2236315) for the full answer.